# Validation in ASP.Net MVC4 for unbound textboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have the following code for a  view, in which I am submitting some data from 3 different text-boxes. This is just a practice sample that I created. I am using Razor syntax  with MVC4 in ASP.Net.

**My question:** How can I validate the text-boxes so they are always required?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HelloWorld";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>HelloWorld</h2>
<div>This is a sample Hello World page</div>
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("HandleSubmit", "Home"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("username", "UserName")
                @Html.TextBox("username")
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("pwd", "Password")
                @Html.Password("pwd")
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("cpwd", "Confirm Password")
                @Html.Password("cpwd")
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="TestPost" />
        <div style="color:red;font-weight:bold">@ViewBag.Feedback</div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** Another way to validate textbox and show a custom invalid message is as below.

```
@Html.TextBox("username", null, new { @required = "required", 
 @oninvalid = "this.setCustomValidity('This data is a must')" })
```

Comment: What do you mean _unbound textboxes_? Are these not properties in a model?

Comment: Its not bound to any property in the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the required attribute in the html attributes parameter for the helper

```
@Html.TextBox("username", null, new { @required="required", @oninvalid="setCustomValidity('I\'m required')" })
```

To customize this and get the same effect as the MVC templates you need `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

```
@Html.TextBox("username", null, new { @data_val_required="I'm required", @data_val="true" })
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="username"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I display a custom message rather than a standard message for above case?

Comment: I've added this to my answer

Comment: I used another format to customize the validation message, as shown under UPDATE 1 of my original post. Does that look ok to you? It seems to work in IE 11.